# かの筆にも言語にも言ひ尽し難き情趣の限なき振動のうちに幽かなる心霊の欷歔をたづね、縹渺たる音楽の愉楽に憧がれて自己観想の悲哀に誇る

Tags: syntax, classical-japanese

> 詩の生命は暗示にして単なる事象の説明には非ず。**かの筆にも言語にも言ひ尽し難き情趣の限なき振動のうちに幽かなる心霊の欷歔をたづね、縹渺たる音楽の愉楽に憧がれて自己観想の悲哀に誇る、これわが象徴の本旨に非ずや**。されば我らは神秘を尚び... [full](http://www.nextftp.com/y_misa/kita/kita_j01.html)

Is it (syntax-wise) correct to take（かの筆にも言語にも言ひ尽し難き情趣の限なき振動のうちに幽かなる心霊の欷歔をたづね、縹渺たる音楽の愉楽に憧がれて自己観想の悲哀に誇る）as a clause that describes これ, and the whole sentence (in 口語) as something like ～るこれは　わが象徴の本旨ではないよ。? I can't make sense of it, because taking it this way contradicts the idea in the previous sentence (or seems to me this way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, これ refers to かの筆にも言語にも言ひ尽し難き情趣の限なき振動のうちに幽かなる心霊の欷歔をたづね、縹渺たる音楽の愉楽に憧がれて自己観想の悲哀に誇る.  Note that かの…誇る does not modify これ, but かの…誇る and これ are in apposition.

What you got incorrectly is …に非ずや.  や signifies a question, including a rhetorical question, which is the case here.  So …に非ずや literally means …ではないか but it actually means …である.

Comment: In plainer terms, 「これ」 here does not mean "this".  It means "to be", "is", etc.  Think of it as "=", the equals sign.

Comment: Yes, this is a kanbun-like wording originally meant to translates the copula 是.